# Can i reduce my taxonomy menu to a top ten list?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I have generated a taxonomy menu out of one of my vocabularies.  But the menu has way too many items.  I would like to shorted it based on number of nodes attached per term so that i can reduce the menu to the top 10 or 20 and implement a *show all* link...

Comment: You can try to do so by using the views module. It allows you to display what you want and provide filters and max-results.

Comment: are you saying that taxonomy_menu and views can be made to work with each other for this or that i simply filter the top ten nodes by terms and output that as a block which can be rendered as a menu?

Comment: thanks for your tip on the views thing.  i think i have come close.  what i did is create a view where i selected the taxonomy term field as the view field twice.  i converted one of them into a count(term_field) and while i was not able to get a top ten kind of thing implemented, i came close by setting a filter on count(term_field) >= 25 by trial and error till i got 9 records.  so i have a nice table with term and counts, now i hope to theme this in the format term A(count), term B(count)... i was able to do all of this by trial and error in the last 1 hour. views is pretty cool!

Comment: I later realized i could limit the records to 10 or whatever rather easily instead of using that filter... but when i remove the filter, i dont know how to limit the terms to 10 or so while picking the top 10 terms AND keeping the terms listed alphabetically.  Is there a way i could re-sort as a post process to ensure i get top ten sorted by term name?

Comment: You can also try to use `hook_taxonomy_menu_insert(&$item)` to control the visibility of menu items

Comment: In the pagination section (bottom of middle column) you can set the amout of items to display (default 50). You can change that to 10, and display no pager. That should work.